# select file dialog with wxWidgets in a command line procedure

Tags: wxwidgets

Is there any way to pop up a wxWidget dialog for selecting files in a command line procedure?
I am new to wxWidgets programming and it seems straightforward to pop up a selecting file dialog with FileDialog class in a wx app.
Here is my c++ code and it works fine within a wx app procedure but not in a command line one.
    #include 
    //#include "wx/osx/filedlg.h"
    #include "wx/wx.h"
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
//IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    wxFileDialog OpenDialog(NULL, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString,
                        _("*"),
                        wxFD_MULTIPLE);
    // Creates a "open file" dialog with 4 file types
   if (OpenDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK) // if the user click "Open" instead of "cancel"
    {
        wxArrayString wx_str_arr;
        OpenDialog.GetFilenames(wx_str_arr);
        /*
         for(size_t i=0; i<wx_str_arr.GetCount(); ++i)
         {
         wxString str = wx_str_arr.Item(i);
         cout<<"str["<<i<<"] = "<<str.c_str().AsChar()<<endl;
         }
         */
        cout<<"count:"<<wx_str_arr.GetCount()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize wxWidgets correctly for this to work, see [wxInitializer class](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_initializer.html) for how to do it in console application.

Note that under Unix, including OS X, there is really absolutely no difference between console and GUI applications, this distinction only exists under Windows.